# @Cacheable in JPA repository class not able to read updated value of enum

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I defined an enum like below:

public enum Strategy {
        DDD, OLD_RATING
    }

I have a mysql table like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DRIVER_STATE_MACHINE")
@Data
public class DriverStateMachine  {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "STATE_ID", nullable = false)
    private int stateId;   

    @Column(name = "STRATEGY", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Strategy strategy;
}
```

There is another class here:

```
public interface DriverStateMachineJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<DriverStateMachine, Integer > {

    @Cacheable("driverStateMachine")
    List<DriverStateMachine> findByStrategyOrderByStateId(Strategy strategy);
}
```

Now if I change OLD_RATING to RATING in strategy and call below function:

```
List<DriverStateMachine> allRules = driverStateMachineJpaRepository.findByStrategyOrderByStateId(Strategy.RATING);
```

I am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown name value [OLD_RATING] for enum class [com.olacabs.ims.workflow.dpe.event.Strategy]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [OLD_RATING] for enum class [com.olacabs.ims.workflow.dpe.event.Strategy]
```

It looks like due to @Cacheable annotation, it is still reading old value of enum. How can I make sure that JPARepository reads updated value ?

Comment: Have you migrated the values in your mysql column as well?

Comment: So you stored the ENUM as a STRING, and then changed the STRING?! and then it can't find the old string

Comment: @Matt yes,.i have changed values in mysql as well.

Comment: @NeilStockton yes, I stored enum as string in db and then changed the enum.. But somehow it is still referring to old value. What is the solution here?

Comment: If it is getting "OLD_RATING" then that has to be from the DB, so you must have not updated something there. The stack trace of that exception would tell you where it comes from, as would the log from your JPA provider

Comment: So "select distinct STRATEGY from DRIVER_STATE_MACHINE" does definitely not show OLD_RATING? Otherwise try a grep -R 'OLD_RATING' on your runtime and source directories. It has to come from somewhere

Comment: @Matt I tried doing grep -R 'OLD_RATING'  from my source directory but I could not find it anywhere. I don't know why is this magic happening.